# Cannot Install angular2-datatable using cli

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to use a table component with sorting and pagination

link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable#mfdata-directive

**Step 1**

```
npm i -S angular2-datatable
```

I got an error message

> D:\Angular2BugTesting>npm i -S angular2-datatable
>   npm WARN @angular/animation@4.0.0-beta.8 requires a peer of
>     @angular/core@4.0.0-beta.8 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN angular2-datatable@0.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0
>     but none was installed.
>   npm WARN angular2-datatable@0.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.0.0 
>     but none was installed.
>   npm WARN angular2-datatable@0.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-
>     browser@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 
>     (node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not 
>     permitted, rename 'D:\Angular2BugTesting\node_modules.staging\fsevents-
>     7e4c9cff\node_modules\ajv' -> 
>     'D:\Angular2BugTesting\node_modules.staging\ajv-2f1711b9'

**Step 2**

I tried to reinstall animation.

```
npm install --save @angular/animations
```

Then tried to re run command still the same problem.

**step3**

```
ng version
```

Which gave the output:

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
node: 6.11.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animation: 4.0.0-beta.8
@angular/animations: 4.3.3
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/common: 4.3.2
@angular/compiler: 4.3.2
@angular/core: 4.3.2
@angular/forms: 4.3.2
@angular/http: 4.3.2
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.2
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.2
@angular/router: 4.3.2
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.2
@angular/language-service: 4.3.2
```

Can anyone suggest how I can solve the problem?

Comment: check for latest updates for packages by using this command **ncu** after updating the packages to latest version. Remove node_modules folder and install npm